# VelocityTemplate, generate list of dates between start and end date

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, velocity

I am sending a batchGetItem API query to AWS DynamoDB which uses Velocity Template to build the query string dynamically. I fetch the `startdate` and `enddate` params. In the following query, I need to collect all the dates between `startdate` and `enddate` params.

I have reviewed the documentation and examples in [here](http://velocitycoder.com/add-and-remove-days-from-date/) and [here](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ComparisonDateTool.html), `ComparisonDateTool()` provides to get years, months or days. But I guess the solution would be complicated with those options (i.e generating the list manually).. So looking for alternative (and possible quick) options..

```
#set($startDate = "$input.params('startdate')")  // ex. 2019-05-27
#set($endDate = "$input.params('enddate')")    // ex. 2019-06-02

... some script to get all dates between start and end date

#set($dates = ["date1", "date2", "date3", ...])

//DynamoDB batchGetItem query
{
    "RequestItems": {
        "tableName": {
            "Keys": [
                "dates": $util.toJson($dates)
             ]
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use your own custom Java tools in the AWS environment, you have to resort to dates and calendars manipulations from within Velocity templates.

```
## parse input dates
#set($start = $date.toDate('yyyy-MM-dd', $startDate))
#set($end = $date.toDate('yyyy-MM-dd', $endDate))

## get calendars
#set($calendar = $date.toCalendar($start))
#set($endCal = $date.toCalendar($end))

## get the number of days
#set($diff = $date.difference($calendar, $endCal).days)

#set($dates = [])

## loop on days
#foreach($day in [0..$diff])
  #set($nextDate = $date.format('yyyy-MM-dd', $calendar))
  $dates.add($nextDate)
  $calendar.add(5, 1) ## '5' means 'days'
#end

...
```

Now `$dates` contains an array of string dates between wanted bounds.